# Accordion using html, css, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

How can I make the text/description (lorem ipsum) disappear before the container close? So that the text/description disappear follow the container.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordion').click(function(){
    $('.description').toggleClass('show')
  })
});
```

```css
body{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Sans-serif';
}
.container{
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.accordion{
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
}
.accordion:hover{
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100)
}
.description{
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: .3s;
}
.description.show{
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="accordion">Accordion</div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati consectetur modi laborum earum expedita ea possimus sed. Consequuntur, non, nostrum corporis nesciunt ipsum est eius laborum quaerat, fuga itaque fugit?
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the `overflow` for the div element with class `description` to `hidden` like below

```
.description{
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: .3s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

So that when the div closes, the content inside does not flow outside it.

Hope it helps